# SQL Select based on value from sub-query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to select a set of users based on the latitude and longitude of another user for whom I have the ID. I need to do a distance calculation in the SELECT statement of the query and am not sure how to access the latitude and longitude of the user that I'm searching against.

Here is my query so far (which doesn't work)

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT u1.latitude, u1.longitude 
     FROM user u1 
     WHERE u1.id = '77c3d4e0-37f6-4fae-b8ac-66cffad07179'), 
    (3959 * acos(cos(radians(u1.latitude))
          * cos(radians(latitude))
          * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(u1.longitude))
    + sin (radians(u1.latitude))
       * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance 
FROM 
    user u2
```

Basically I want to get all of the columns from user and a column called distance, which is the distance from the user with the ID

Comment: `"77c3d4e0-37f6-4fae-b8ac-66cffad07179"` seams to be wrong, double quotes are for identifiers like table names and columns, for string values you should be using single quotes, iám very much tempted to voteclose this question to be a simple typographical error

Comment: Do you have 2 tables: user and icebreaker_user?

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: I have corrected the typo. Gordon Linoff's answer is what I was looking for. I didn't think to use a JOIN for some reason

Comment: Also take a look into [PostGis](https://postgis.net/) which has better functions to calculate this.

Comment: I did look into it but it doesn't co-operate with the ORM I'm using and seemed to be overkill as this is the only lat, lng calculation I will be doing. If I run into issues maybe I will have to try that route again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the subquery reference to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT u2.*, 
       (3959 * acos (
           cos ( radians(u1.latitude) )
           * cos( radians( u2.latitude ) )
           * cos( radians( u2.longitude ) - radians(u1.longitude) )
           + sin ( radians(u1.latitude) )
           * sin( radians( u2.latitude ) )
         )
       ) AS distance
FROM icebreaker_user u2 JOIN
     icebreaker_user u1
     ON u1.id = '77c3d4e0-37f6-4fae-b8ac-66cffad07179'
```